# Passing a variable as a column name through pyspark Expr

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to loop through each column of a date frame based on conditions and pass each column name iteration into the expression.

The problem, with the below is that pyspark thinks that `columnName` is the name of a column and not a variable which corresponds to a column. How can I do this?

```py
df_excelDate= df1.withColumn('excelDate',  expr("case when columnName>0 AND columnName< datediff(current_timestamp(),to_date('1899-12-31', 'yyyy-MM-dd')) then True when columnName IS NULL  then NULL else False end"))
```

Comment: just use format(): `expr("case when {0}>0 AND {0} <......".format(columnName))`

Comment: @jxc I've never used format. Is there a link to some documentation on the web or can you give a simple example? or is that how it should look?
(
e.g ```expr("{0} + 1 > 2*{0)".format(variableName))```

would be a variable +1 > 2 times the variable in the expression

Comment: check https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples, this is basically a pure Python question on how to format a string which you can use in expr() function.